# How To Fix Nvidia Driver 384.90 From Causing fsck from running On 17.10 Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

Recently after installing the stable and final beta of 17.10, I was able to reboot fine and download updates, however, after going into 'Additional Drivers', and setting the proprietary drivers to my Intel Drivers, and my Nvidia GPU to the 384.90 driver, I am now brought to a screen that says: SDB1: Clean XXXXX / XXXXX files; XXXXXX / XXXXXX blocks,   after booting into my ubuntu partition.

I love the new version of Ubuntu and so far the only fixes I have found are by always booting into recovery and setting the FSCK to 0 upon startup, which is reset every reboot, and purging 'xdiagnose'. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: `fsck` always runs on every boot. Presumably, your real problem is that nothing happens afterwards, but that's hardly `fsck`'s fault.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an issue with the nvidia drivers. it is possibly because of kernel update or fsck update or plymouth update. It used to do the scan without report to the GUI splash screen. now when fsck starts it flashes a message on the GUI even if the drives are set to not be scanned.

The fix to prevent fsck from starting is to edit your /etc/fstab file.
The fstab entries should look something like:

```
UUID=<uuid>  /  ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

the last digit tells fsck which pass to scan the partition. Possible values are 0,1,2.
Setting it to zero for all mounts will keep fsck from launching and passing any messages.

Note: this also means that you will have to manually check your file system periodically.

Comment: I am curious to know why it didn't do this until I updated the NVIDIA driver

Comment: I don't know, I don't use nvidia. before the boot splash would run perfect. though if looking at the text it would give the scan message. after an update. it started flashing the message on the boot animation. Perhaps a change in error reporting level.

Comment: Changing your /etc/fstab file to change the fsck pass count to zero is **NOT A GOOD IDEA**. The message that you see just tells you that the file system check passed without errors. Without the fsck, you could compound small fixable errors into larger unfixable problems. Leave it all alone.

Comment: @heynnema -- my drives are set by the system not to be scanned at all. thus no reason for fsck to be launched by fstab since it only starts then shuts down. And secondly I did say that manual scans would have to be done regularly

Comment: @ravery disabling fsck is **NOT A GOOD IDEA** period. And... **users won't do manual fsck's**... especially with the frequency required. The fsck adds almost no time to the boot sequence, so why disable this useful tool?